# Rated voltage vs rated power on lamp holder

Tags: lamp

I bought a string of lights from America (110V, 25W per socket, 50 sockets (1250W total) to use in South Africa (power supply is 220/230V 50Hz).

I thought I could just use a converter (220V to 110V) and 25W incandescent bulbs.

But now I wonder if I really need a converter? The resistor is the actual bulb, which I will buy here and will therefore be rated 25W at 220V.

Surely that will be fine? I figure 1250W/110V=11.4A for the string or 25W/110V=0.23A for the socket. Or 1250W/220V=5.7A for the string or 25W/220V=0.11A for the socket.

Does current make a difference? These are just lights, not electronics, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lamp sockets are presumably rated at 110V - this means if you use 220V you may be endangering someone due to not having sufficient insulation built in to cope with the higher voltage. Play safe.

Comment: So can we tell from this? - http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00FUC9EU0?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00

Comment: And then the obvious question that lead me to wonder about this: can I use the 220V bulbs in that lamp holder with 110V input? I don't care if they're dim. I would actually buy 11W bulbs if we could get them here.

Comment: These are outdoor use lamp holders. I wouldn't even consider plugging them in to 220V. You might kill someone. Without a definitive statement from the manufacturer you are taking risks that I see as unreasonable. Either use a step down transformer or don't use them is my advice.

Comment: Will 220V lamps mechanically fit? If so this is a safe option with a 110V supply.

Comment: Yeah they fit, I did check that. So why is that dangerous? I don't see why if the bulbs themselves are rated at the correct power? And step-down transformer or just a converter?

Comment: I'm saying NOT dangerous = 220V bulbs on a 110V supply

Comment: Ok, I understand but why is 220V supply dangerous? Gets hot? It will melt, explode?

Comment: The electrical insulation is designed for use with 110VAC.  It may be too thin or otherwise not suitable for use with 220VAC.  You end up with a shock hazard - someone may touch something that appears to be insulated and still get shocked.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136981/whats-more-dangerous-110v-or-240v Electrocution is the key worry.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That article says that lower current is better (ie. the higher voltage  means lower current). But I don't understand it all. I will try to find out if those sockets can handle the voltage. The wires are extremely well-insulated, which is why I bought the thing. The ones here are hand made.

Comment: JRE thank you. That I understand now and I will find out about the insulation. This explains it more: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51966/does-voltage-play-any-role-in-choosing-the-appropriate-wire-gauge