# Is earth wire of any help in this situation

Tags: earth

I have an appliance that has the wires connected well and it has been grounded (earthed). If I accidentally get into contact with a live wire will I get electrocuted considering it has already been earthed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How grounding works to prevent electrical shock](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152291/how-grounding-works-to-prevent-electrical-shock)

Answer (score 1):

Getting into contact with a live wire will likely cause electrocution.

If an appliance is earthed, this prevents you getting electrocuted from exposed metal parts should they somehow come into contact with a live connection. When this happens the fuse will blow and the live connection will be dead.

Directly coming into contact with a live wire (that is still live) means electrocution irrespective of the exposed metal parts being earthed. Don't try this at home.

Comment: Or at school ...

Comment: Or anywhere really