# Electrical service discharge path through body

Tags: voltage, grounding, discharge, routing, lightning

If someone were to accidentally make contact with live service conductors, while touching another person, would I get shocked or would the current travel through me and into the other party without my being hurt? The same scenario but a live wire falls onto a vehicle with passengers inside,if the driver tries to step out of the car would they be injured? If the driver stays inside, but I were to be touching another party outside the vehicle and then attempt to open the door, would the driver or me be hurt?

Comment: *would I get shocked or would the current travel through me and into the other party without my being hurt?* ... what do you think that causes `getting shocked`?

Comment: I once read of an account of an electrical accident in Italy in the 1890s, when electric light was still quite new, of a 'chain' of dead people resulting when a maid got up some steps to clean an electric ceiling light and got a shock, a nearby servant climbed up to help her, touched her, was electrocuted, and so were two or three more in like fashion. I think all had wet hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If someone were to accidentally make contact with live service conductors, while touching another person, would I get shocked or would the current travel through me and into the other party without my being hurt?

The current will travel through both you and the other person, and both will get shocked.

Safety manuals will tell you that you shouldn't touch a person who is being shocked.  When you have to detach another person from a source of shock, you should use an insulating object (wooden plank, some tool with long a plastic shaft, or such).

[Dangerous.  Do not attempt.]
There is a rural prank with an electric fence.  The prankster puts on rubber boots, and grabs the electric fence.  The current doesn't flow through him - yet - because electric fences are under DC potential, and the rubber boots break the return path to ground.  Then the prankster asks the victim to come over, greets him cordially, and shakes hands with him.  The victim isn't wearing rubber boots, so he completes the circuit.  Both the victim and the prankster get shocked.  But the victim is not expecting it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the example. I had not thought about it in that manner before. What If all involved wore rubber boots. And, I would suspect that there are rubber soles and RUBBER Soles...At what point does the grade of the shoe become negligible? Or become enough? Other than trial and error, how does one know? I also suspect that the benefits of the insulating material will be outweighed by the magnitude of the voltage and or amperage? I am sure that ASTM has ways of measuring such, but how does the layperson relate to it?

Comment: Electric shock *is* current.  Protection against electric shock is reduction of current to safe levels.  Here's a [chart](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/129306/7036).  Electric fences are DC (although higher voltage than house AC).  AC will have the return path through capacitive coupling.  Why are you asking?  What kind of issue or device is on your mind?