# When does a human body get shocked by electricity

Tags: safety, shock

Today I touched the live phase of the electrical line of my house wearing rubber shoes.
However, I still got an electric shock

As I wore rubber shoes it seems to me that I shouldn't be get shocked. As there is no conduction through my body to ground.

Why did I get an electric shock?

What will happen if I touch only a phase of 11KV transmission line with no contact with the ground, or touching anything with my body?

Comment: Conductor (salty bag aka body), thin insulator (aka sole of shoes), ground. Sounds like a capacitor to me.

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-3/ohms-law-again/ Read this

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design - question should be closed.

Comment: if you touch an 11kV power line without touching anything else you would suffocate because of lack of oxygen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much voltage is "dangerous"?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/how-much-voltage-is-dangerous)

Comment: Watch the attached video for your 11kV question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWbBdAeW1m8

Answer (score 1):

> As I wore rubber shoes it seems to me that I shouldn't be get shocked. As there is no conduction through my body to ground.

Only in theroy.

Your feet produce sweat, and good shoes have a way for the water to get out. Unfortunately, that is the same way for electrical current to get into your body.

Answer (score 0):

Electrocution may be caused by different reasons with different consequences. It may be 50Hz disrupting your heart rhythm or high current burning your skin. I know at least one case of lethal electrocution with 12V battery. So it's a complex question with no simple answer.