# A High Voltage AC or a High Voltage DC which is more dangerous for human?

Tags: power-supply

Not going too **High** Potential.

Say a 200V supply.

If somebody accidentally touches the bare terminals of supply,
for which case ( AC or DC ), the effect on the person will be more
dangerous.

And in which particular case more precaution should be taken ?

Comment: Don't think anything Weird, I am not planing to kill somebody. Just wanted to know.

Comment: is that 200Vrms vs 200Vdc  or 141Vrms vs 200Vdc. 

There is a reason the EU have set the low voltage directive at 50Vac,75Vdc because above that there is harm. 

http://ec.europa.eu/growth/sectors/electrical-engineering/lvd-directive/index_en.htm

Comment: 200Vrms vs 200Vdc

Comment: 200Vac then as the peak is 282V, this is dependent on the source impedance as well. But both are dangerous. Its like saying "what will kill you more, a lion or a lion missing one tooth"

Comment: Yes, it is. It is an arbitrary value. My point is Voltage is pretty High. But not too High as used for transmission.

Comment: iirc edison organized public executions of (big) animals with AC, calling it "to be westinghoused" to demonstrate how much more dangerous AC is than DC. Generally it is considered that the DC current required to kill is much higher than the AC current.

Answer (score 0):

Both will potentially kill you, but in that voltage region where it will not instantaneously kill you, the so-called let-go threshold is the most relevant. We were though in school that DC will cause harder cramps but measured and observed results tells otherwise. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/how-much-voltage-is-dangerous)
When you are have touched a conductor at that voltage, you might be stuck there waiting for someone to break the voltage or your own death, whichever comes first.

EDIT: Revised answer from PlasmaHH's link. Thanks!

Comment: The AC let-go threshold is considered to be between 3-22mA while the DC let-go threshold is considered to be between 15-88mA, similar differences for the actual currents needed to kill.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Interesting! In my own accidents and experiments, AC is very unpleasant but DC will really lock your mussels and grip. Where did you get the numbers from?

Comment: These specific numbers are from my personal test protocol documentation, however googling for AC vs DC let-go thresholds gives varying numbers in those ranges, all mention higher values for DC and if it comes to "hurts more" there is nothing more entertaining than the electroboom video of it. Also there are questions on this site that dealt with it: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19103/

Comment: @PlasmaHH. Good stuff. Seems they lied to us in school. I'll edit my answer.